# Executavel criado pelo CodeBlocks abre e fecha sozinho

Tags: c, c++, arquivo, sdl, codeblocks

Estou com um problema com meu programa no CodeBlocks.
Quando eu compilo e executo o programa, o CodeBlocks cria um executavel na pasta Debug que fica dentro da pasta bin, localizada na mesma pasta onde se encontra o projeto. Ao tentar abrir o .exe dessa pasta Debug, ele simplesmente abre e fecha, em uma fração de segundo, porém, compilando e executando no CodeBlocks, o programa funciona normalmente, esperando que o usuário pressione o X da janela ou aperte ESC do teclado. Eu fiz o programa usando C++ e SDL 2.0, segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#define SCREEN_W 800
#define SCREEN_H 600

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* windowSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* imagem = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
    SDL_Event event;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        SDL_Log("%s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    if (!IMG_Init(imgFlags) & imgFlags) {
        SDL_Log("%s\n",IMG_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    imagem = IMG_Load("camaro.png");
    if (imagem == NULL) {
        SDL_Log("%s\n",IMG_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Nome", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == NULL) {
        SDL_Log("%s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    if (windowSurface == NULL) {
        SDL_Log("%s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (renderer == NULL) {
        SDL_Log("%s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, imagem);
    if (texture == NULL) {
        SDL_Log("%s\n",SDL_GetError());
        SDL_FreeSurface(imagem);
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(imagem);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);

    while(!quit) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE: quit = true; break;
                    default: break;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Quem souber resolver, agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Quando um programa é executado sem utilizar o terminal à falsa sensação de que ele abre e fecha. Isso ocorre porque ao executar com dois cliques ele abre, executa e como chegou ao final ele fecha a janela... Para ver o console/janela faça o programa aguardar por algo como por exemplo o usuário pressionar enter

```
int main()
{
    /*
     * Codigo do programa
    */

    cin.get(); // Ira fazer o programa aguardar um enter para ir pro final
    return 0;
}
```

Caso pesquise você ira encontrar alguns códigos onde no final contem SDL_Delay( x )

```
int main()
{
    /*
     * Codigo do programa
    */

    SDL_Delay( 2000 ); // Para a execução do programa por 2 segundos
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```